# How do I keep the position of my image fixed with respect to the background image in my HTML page?

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, html, jquery-animate

I have a HTML page where I have put the background image in body css.

```
body {
    /*cursor: URL("target.png"),pointer;*/
    background-color:#202020;
    background-image: url('../Images/BGimage.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Now when i put a new image in html page say,

```
<img src="target.png" style="position:absolute;margin-top:280px;margin-left:700px;z-index:1" />
```

The position of image changes when I go full screen or minimize the window.The background image is fixed but the new image shifts. How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Should the image remain in a relative position to it's point on the background image?

Comment: You would need to play with percentage left, top and transform properties.

Comment: @Ritesh something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/dd8k66yj/

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="target.png" style="position:absolute;top:280px;left:700px;z-index:1" />
```

Using top and left you can set the position horizontally and vertically of the image then it won't move because it is at that position in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

<s>If you want a smaller image to overlay a non-repeating background image in a permanently fixed position relative to the background image, then you might as well just open the background image in an image-editing application, copy and paste the smaller image into the canvas, position it the way you want, and save it as a new image file. You can then use that new image file as the background image.</s>

Of course, this will not work if you need to apply dynamic changes to the smaller image during the lifetime of the page, such as transitions, or dynamic changes to its CSS. But otherwise, I would think this would be the best solution.

---

I've looked more closely at this problem. Because you require dynamic changes to the smaller image, embedding it in the background image will not work. Rather, it will be necessary to compute and specify the exact position of the smaller image in the containing element such that it overlays the background image in the exact location that you want.

To accomplish this task, it is necessary to determine the final, absolute position of the background image relative to the containing element.

---

## CSS property value sequence

It is important to understand that CSS property values undergo a complex calculation process which may incorporate browser defaults, CSS source declarations, specificity, inheritance, interdependent property interactions, layout-dependent resolutions of relative values, and in some cases rounding/approximations.

We can summarize this process by listing the distinct stages of values that can come into play during this calculation sequence:

[**initial value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) Used as the browser default for the root element. Also used as the browser default for non-root elements for non-inherited properties (inherited properties can inherit the initial value from the root, or their parent, if not overidden in their lineage or self-styling).

[**source value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax) The value explicitly specified in the document's source (file links, style tags, and inline style attributes). This takes into account CSS's cascading rules to select the most specific rule for the element/pseudo-element.

[**specified value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/specified_value) The source value if given, otherwise the inherited value (for inherited properties) or the initial value (for non-inherited properties). Note that a source value may itself be set to the literal bareword `inherit` or `initial`.

[**computed value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) A derivation from the specified value that resolves `inherit` and `initial` to get more concrete values, plus applies additional transformations such as span `position:absolute` changing to `display:block`. Pre-layout.

[**used value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/used_value) The final value after all calculations have been performed. Post-layout. Resolves auto and percentages to absolute pixel values.

[**actual value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/actual_value) The used value after all approximations have been applied. For example, a user agent may only be able to render borders with an integer pixel value and may be forced to approximate the computed width of the border.

---

Confusingly, the [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) function does *not* return computed values, but rather returns something called resolved values:

[**resolved value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolved_value) Returned by `getComputedStyle()`. (1) For `line-height` it is always the used value. (2) Otherwise, for elements/pseudo-elements (a) with `display:none`, or (b) for which the property does not ever apply, or (c) for an over-constrained `bottom`, `left`, `right`, or `top`, it is always the computed value (because their layout cannot be determined, in most cases). (3) Otherwise, for `bottom`, `left`, `right`, `top`, `width`, `height`, `padding`, and `margin` properties, it is always the used value. (4) Otherwise, it is always the computed value.

---

## The Problem

The problem is that we need the position of the *background image*. A background image is not an element in itself, and thus we cannot get its position from its CSS used values, since it has no CSS values of its own. Furthermore, due to the complexities of background image placement, its exact position can vary in subtle ways from the position of its containing element depending on (1) the values of [`background-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin), [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), and [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position), (2) the original background image size, and (3) the containing element size, which itself can depend on the sizing of the user's browser window, which can change dynamically.

Of course, there exist permutations of values for the above three CSS properties that would fix the background image in place relative to its containing element, and would allow us to statically determine the absolute position that would place the smaller image at the desired location relative to the background image, regardless of any other details. But for your case, since you have `background-size:contain` and `background-position:center center`, this does not apply here.

In the general case, we need to calculate the position of the background image dynamically based on the above three CSS properties of the containing element, as well as other CSS properties of the containing element (specifically padding and, for the case of `background-origin:border-box`, borders), the original image size, and the containing element size.

---

## The Solution

The solution requires a JavaScript function to calculate the position of the background image in the containing element.

Note that I've been using the term "background position" somewhat loosely in description of the target computation, but it should be clarified that in order to calculate the required position of the smaller image, we will need to compute both the top-left corner *and* the bottom-right corner of the background image. In other words, we need to ascertain the entire bounding box of the background image in order to be able to calculate the coordinates of the target location in the background image where we want the smaller image to be placed.

**Why `getComputedStyle().backgroundPosition` cannot be used directly**

You may think that we should be able to get the final absolute position of the background image with `getComputedStyle().backgroundPosition` run on the containing element. This is not correct. The reason is that we need the final *used values* of the background image position. As described earlier, `getComputedStyle()` only returns used values for a few CSS properties, and even then only in some cases, and `backgroundPosition` is not among them.

Also, as explained a moment ago, we will also need the bottom-right corner of the background image, whereas `backgroundPosition` would only return the top-left corner. We could derive the bottom-right corner by also getting `getComputedStyle().backgroundSize`, but `backgroundSize` suffers from the same limitation as `backgroundPosition`, in that it would only give us computed values rather than used values.

**Browser API Solutions**

I briefly searched for provisions in browser APIs that could be used to get the used values of the above two CSS properties, but unfortunately there do not appear to be any. See [Is there a cross-browser method of getting the used css values of all properties of all elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970655/is-there-a-cross-browser-method-of-getting-the-used-css-values-of-all-properties), which doesn't satisfactorily answer the question, and none of the conversants appear to be aware of the concept of *resolved values*, and that the `getComputedStyle()` function returns computed values for most cases.

**Existing JavaScript Solutions**

I did some searching to see if anyone has already come up with a JavaScript solution to this problem. The closest seems to be the JavaScript function given in [Get final size of background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999515/get-final-size-of-background-image/30000591#30000591). Unfortunately, that function only computes the *size* of background image, so it is not enough. (And I don't think it works for all cases, but I haven't verified this.)

**Solution**

So, I've written my own JavaScript function to solve this problem.

Recall that `getComputedStyle().backgroundPosition` and `getComputedStyle.backgroundSize` do not give us the final used values of those two properties; they only give us computed values. But those computed values provide us a necessary starting point to manually calculate the used values that a standards-conforming browser will arrive at when laying out the containing element and its background image.

So, in my function, I get the above two computed values along with `getComputedStyle().backgroundOrigin`, along with the padding and border CSS values, and proceed to calculate the bounding box of the background image appropriately for the current permutation of values. We have to handle all three possible values of `backgroundOrigin`, percentages and absolute pixel values for `backgroundPosition`, and percentages, absolute pixel values, `auto`, and `cover` and `contain` for `backgroundSize`.

Below I present the function as part of a complete working demo. I went a little overboard and found a picture of the Earth for the background image, a picture of the International Space Station with transparency for the smaller image, defined three different locations in the background image specified as percentages into its width and height, and provided controls which allow (1) transitioning between the three different locations and (2) resizing the containing element dynamically, triggering the smaller image to recalculate its required absolute pixel position in order to remain at the currently selected location within the background image.

```js
window.getBackgroundImageBox = function(elem,i) {
  // elem -- the element that instantiates the background image
  // i -- the index into the list of background images set in the CSS

  // there are 8 specific CSS background properties:
  //
  //   background-image: assume this is set to an image URL
  //   background-position: will get resolved value, must calculate used value
  //   background-size: will get resolved value, must calculate used value
  //   background-repeat: assume this is set to no-repeat
  //   background-origin: must take this into account when determining pos and size
  //   background-clip: can ignore this; only clips, doesn't change actual image pos and size
  //   background-attachment: assume either scroll (default), or fixed with no scrolling, so ignore this
  //   background-color: not relevant to pos and size

  // default i if not given
  if (i === undefined) i = 0;

  // get resolved origin, size, and pos
  let computedStyle = getComputedStyle(elem);
  let resolvedOrigin = computedStyle.backgroundOrigin.split(', ')[i];
  let resolvedSize = computedStyle.backgroundSize.split(', ')[i];
  let resolvedPos = computedStyle.backgroundPosition.split(', ')[i];
  // get resolved elem width and height
  let resolvedWidth = computedStyle.width.split(', ')[i];
  let resolvedHeight = computedStyle.height.split(', ')[i];
  let elemWidth = parseInt(resolvedWidth.replace('px',''),10);
  let elemHeight = parseInt(resolvedHeight.replace('px',''),10);
  // get resolved border sizes
  let borderLeft = !computedStyle.borderLeftWidth ? 0 : parseInt(computedStyle.borderLeftWidth.replace('px',''),10);
  let borderTop = !computedStyle.borderTopWidth ? 0 : parseInt(computedStyle.borderTopWidth.replace('px',''),10);
  let borderRight = !computedStyle.borderRightWidth ? 0 : parseInt(computedStyle.borderRightWidth.replace('px',''),10);
  let borderBottom = !computedStyle.borderBottomWidth ? 0 : parseInt(computedStyle.borderBottomWidth.replace('px',''),10);
  // get resolved padding sizes
  let paddingLeft = !computedStyle.paddingLeft ? 0 : parseInt(computedStyle.paddingLeft.replace('px',''),10);
  let paddingTop = !computedStyle.paddingTop ? 0 : parseInt(computedStyle.paddingTop.replace('px',''),10);
  let paddingRight = !computedStyle.paddingRight ? 0 : parseInt(computedStyle.paddingRight.replace('px',''),10);
  let paddingBottom = !computedStyle.paddingBottom ? 0 : parseInt(computedStyle.paddingBottom.replace('px',''),10);

  // derive actual bounding box, which could be different from content box due to origin
  let byOriginLeft;
  let byOriginTop;
  let byOriginRight;
  let byOriginBottom;
  if (resolvedOrigin === 'content-box') {
    byOriginLeft = paddingLeft;
    byOriginTop = paddingTop;
    byOriginRight = paddingLeft+elemWidth;
    byOriginBottom = paddingTop+elemHeight;
  } else if (resolvedOrigin === 'padding-box') {
    byOriginLeft = 0;
    byOriginTop = 0;
    byOriginRight = paddingLeft+elemWidth+paddingRight;
    byOriginBottom = paddingTop+elemHeight+paddingBottom;
  } else if (resolvedOrigin === 'border-box') {
    byOriginLeft = -borderLeft;
    byOriginTop = -borderTop;
    byOriginRight = paddingLeft+elemWidth+paddingRight+borderRight;
    byOriginBottom = paddingTop+elemHeight+paddingBottom+borderBottom;
  } else {
    throw 'unsupported origin: '+resolvedOrigin;
  } // end if
  let byOriginWidth = byOriginRight-byOriginLeft;
  let byOriginHeight = byOriginBottom-byOriginTop;

  // create image object to get original image's size
  let image = new Image();
  image.src = computedStyle.backgroundImage.split(', ')[i].replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi,'$2').replace(/\\(.)/,'$1'); // note: don't have to decode URI to assign, but must manually strip backslash escape codes
  let imageWidth = image.width;
  let imageHeight = image.height;

  // get original image y/x ratio, and elem y/x ratio
  let imageRatio = imageHeight/imageWidth;
  let elemRatio = elemHeight/elemWidth;

  // compute initial idea of the result based on origin and size; will apply position afterward
  if (resolvedSize === 'cover') {

    if (elemRatio > imageRatio) { // more height in elem than image => flush height, surplus width
      res = {
        'left':byOriginLeft,
        'top':byOriginTop,
        'right':byOriginLeft+byOriginHeight/imageRatio,
        'bottom':byOriginBottom
      };
    } else { // more width in elem than image => flush width, surplus height
      res = {
        'left':byOriginLeft,
        'top':byOriginTop,
        'right':byOriginRight,
        'bottom':byOriginTop+byOriginWidth*imageRatio
      };
    } // end if

  } else if (resolvedSize === 'contain') {

    if (elemRatio > imageRatio) { // more height in elem than image => flush width, deficient height
      res = {
        'left':byOriginLeft,
        'top':byOriginTop,
        'right':byOriginRight,
        'bottom':byOriginTop+byOriginWidth*imageRatio
      };
    } else { // more width in elem than image => flush height, deficient width
      res = {
        'left':byOriginLeft,
        'top':byOriginTop,
        'right':byOriginLeft+byOriginHeight/imageRatio,
        'bottom':byOriginBottom
      };
    } // end if

  } else {

    // parse size into width and height values
    let resolvedSizeSplit = resolvedSize.split(' ');
    let resolvedSizeWidth = resolvedSizeSplit[0];
    let resolvedSizeHeight = resolvedSizeSplit.length >= 2 ? resolvedSizeSplit[1] : 'auto'; // resolved always has both in FF, but not IE

    // resolve to integer width and height values
    let sizeWidth;
    let sizeHeight;
    if (resolvedSizeWidth === 'auto' && resolvedSizeHeight === 'auto') {
      // double auto uses original img size
      sizeWidth = imageWidth;
      sizeHeight = imageHeight;
    } else {
      // if not double auto, calculate non-auto first, then resolve auto if exists
      if (resolvedSizeWidth !== 'auto') {
        if (resolvedSizeWidth.indexOf('%') > -1) {
          let sizeWidthPct = parseInt(resolvedSizeWidth.replace('%',''));
          sizeWidth = sizeWidthPct*byOriginWidth/100;
        } else {
          sizeWidth = parseInt(resolvedSizeWidth.replace('px',''));
        } // end if
      } // end if
      if (resolvedSizeHeight !== 'auto') {
        if (resolvedSizeHeight.indexOf('%') > -1) {
          let sizeHeightPct = parseInt(resolvedSizeHeight.replace('%',''));
          sizeHeight = sizeHeightPct*byOriginHeight/100;
        } else {
          sizeHeight = parseInt(resolvedSizeHeight.replace('px',''));
        } // end if
      } // end if
      // resolve dependent auto
      if (resolvedSizeWidth === 'auto') sizeWidth = sizeHeight/imageRatio;
      if (resolvedSizeHeight === 'auto') sizeHeight = sizeWidth*imageRatio;
    } // end if

    res = {
      'left':byOriginLeft,
      'top':byOriginTop,
      'right':byOriginLeft+sizeWidth,
      'bottom':byOriginTop+sizeHeight
    };

  } // end if

  // get absolute pos value in pixels
  let resolvedPosSplit = resolvedPos.split(' ');
  let resolvedPosLeft = resolvedPosSplit[0];
  let resolvedPosTop = resolvedPosSplit.length >= 2 ? resolvedPosSplit[1] : '50%'; // resolved always has both in FF, but not IE
  let posLeft;
  let isPosLeftPct;
  if (resolvedPosLeft.indexOf('%') > -1) {
    isPosLeftPct = true;
    let posLeftPct = parseInt(resolvedPosLeft.replace('%',''));
    posLeft = posLeftPct*(byOriginWidth-(res.right-res.left))/100;
  } else {
    isPosLeftPct = false;
    posLeft = parseInt(resolvedPosLeft.replace('px',''));
  } // end if
  let posTop;
  let isPosTopPct;
  if (resolvedPosTop.indexOf('%') > -1) {
    isPosTopPct = true;
    let posTopPct = parseInt(resolvedPosTop.replace('%',''));
    posTop = posTopPct*(byOriginHeight-(res.bottom-res.top))/100;
  } else {
    isPosTopPct = false;
    posTop = parseInt(resolvedPosTop.replace('px',''));
  } // end if

  // apply pos
  // tricky: must *not* apply pct pos adjustment to flush dimension for cover and contain
  if (!(
    isPosLeftPct && (
      resolvedSize === 'cover' && elemRatio < imageRatio
      || resolvedSize === 'contain' && elemRatio > imageRatio
    )
  )) {
    res.left += posLeft;
    res.right += posLeft;
  } // end if
  if (!(
    isPosTopPct && (
      resolvedSize === 'cover' && elemRatio > imageRatio
      || resolvedSize === 'contain' && elemRatio < imageRatio
    )
  )) {
    res.top += posTop;
    res.bottom += posTop;
  } // end if

  return res;

};

// global constants
var SMALLERIMAGE_LEFTPCT = [67,90,15];
var SMALLERIMAGE_TOPPCT  = [64,10,70];
var MULT = 1.2;

// global variables
var g_pctIndex = 0;

// state change functions
window.updateSmallerImage = function() {

  let leftPct = SMALLERIMAGE_LEFTPCT[g_pctIndex];
  let topPct = SMALLERIMAGE_TOPPCT[g_pctIndex];

  // get the smaller image element and its containing element
  let smallerImageElem = document.getElementById('smallerImage');
  let containingElem = smallerImageElem.parentElement;

  // get the bounding box of the background image in the containing element
  let bgbox = getBackgroundImageBox(containingElem);

  // get the computed style of the smaller image element
  let computedStyle = getComputedStyle(smallerImageElem);

  // move the smaller image to the required position
  // note: subtracting half the width and height for centering, but could do it differently
  // must use computedStyle for the subtraction in case the inline style attribute has not been set yet
  smallerImageElem.style.left = (bgbox.left + (bgbox.right-bgbox.left)*leftPct/100 - computedStyle.width.replace('px','')/2)+'px';
  smallerImageElem.style.top = (bgbox.top + (bgbox.bottom-bgbox.top)*topPct/100 - computedStyle.height.replace('px','')/2)+'px';

  // ensure the smaller image is displayed
  smallerImageElem.style.display = 'block';

};

window.multContainingElementDim = function(prop,mult) {
  let containingElem = document.getElementById('containingElement');
  let computedStyle = getComputedStyle(containingElem);
  containingElem.style[prop] = (computedStyle[prop].replace('px','')*mult)+'px';
};

window.advanceSmallerIndexPctIndex = function() {
  g_pctIndex = (g_pctIndex+1)%SMALLERIMAGE_LEFTPCT.length;
  let indexButton = document.getElementById('indexButton');
  indexButton.value = '['+g_pctIndex+']';
  updateSmallerImage();
};

window.onload = function() {
  updateSmallerImage();
  let containingElem = document.getElementById('containingElement');
  containingElem.addEventListener('transitionend',updateSmallerImage,false);
};
```

```css
#containingElement {
  position:relative;
  background-color:#202020;
  background-image:url('http://media.zenfs.com/en_US/News/BGR_News/planet-earth.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center center;
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  transition:
    width 0.3s ease-in-out,
    height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#smallerImage {
  position:absolute;
  width:80px;
  height:32px;
  display:none; /* will show after positioning */
  transition:
    left 0.3s ease-in-out,
    top 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#controls {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="controls">
  <input type="button" value="▲" onclick="multContainingElementDim('height',1/MULT);"/>
  <input type="button" value="◄" onclick="multContainingElementDim('width',1/MULT);"/>
  <input type="button" value="►" onclick="multContainingElementDim('width',MULT);"/>
  <input type="button" value="▼" onclick="multContainingElementDim('height',MULT);"/>
  &nbsp;
  <input id="indexButton" type="button" value="[0]" onclick="advanceSmallerIndexPctIndex();"/>
</div>

<div id="containingElement">
  <img id="smallerImage" src="https://i0.wp.com/freepngimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/international-space-station-transparent-background.png"/>
</div>
```

**Testing**

I tested the primary implementation function `getBackgroundImageBox()` extremely thoroughly in Firefox, trying 810 different permutations for the aforementioned three properties, and it worked perfectly for them all. I did much less thorough spot checking in Chrome and Internet Explorer. All checks worked in Chrome, but unfortunately Internet Explorer failed for a couple of cases, which appeared to be because the values it was returning for `getComputedStyle().backgroundSize` were flat-out incorrect for those failing cases. I have not figured out the reason for the failure or if there is a possible workaround, so be aware of this issue.

That being said, for your particular CSS, everything appears to be working. The primary implementation function as well as the entire demo seem to be working based on my testing in all of Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer.

Comment: I need to apply dynamic changes. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: What dynamic changes do you need to apply?

Comment: i need to animate the image on top of background image to a new position on background image.

Answer (score 1):

To fix image in right even in resizing mode, you need position:relative to parent (in your case, body tag). So simple give `position;relative` to body tag and you are done.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/dd8k66yj/)

**Update HTML**

```
<img src="target.png" style="position:absolute;margin-top:280px;right:70px;z-index:1" />
```

**Updated CSS**

```
body {
    /*cursor: URL("target.png"),pointer;*/
    background-color:#202020;
    background-image: url('../Images/BGimage.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I thought the same but it is not working. The problem is the background images re-sizes since it is responsive in nature. Now, since it re-sizes, the original images changes with respect to body tag and not background image.

Comment: This is my original css code:- html,
body{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url('Images/BGimage.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    /*background-attachment:fixed;*/
}

Answer (score 0):

you can try **margin** percentage instead of pixel

Comment: margin percentage results in the same kind of problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can try position:fixed css style. That will fix your picture regardless you maximize or minimize the screen.

```
style{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:280px;
    margin-left:700px;
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: And by this if user will resize window, he will not be able to see image.. what a solution!!!