# Why does it takes to click to apply my function?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm trying to write a code that when you click the button it shows and when pressed again it hides images. I made that images **display** to **none** and I want it to change to **block** when pressed the button (so it shows the images).

It works, but ***only when you click twice***.
What should I do to activate it on one click?

HTML :

```
<button id="categoryBtn" onclick="insta()">instagram users</button>
```

javascript :

```
function insta() {
  var a = document.getElementById("instaBalas");

  if (a.style.display == "none") {
    a.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    a.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: The `style` object only shows properties that were explicitly set in the original HTML, or changed later by JavaScript. Thus when the function runs the first time, the "display" property will be `undefined`, not "block".

Comment: Because `#instaBalas` does not have `display:none` initially :/, so it takes two clicks to eventually add block.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you click first time the display is empty string. So its then set to `'none'` and works normally after. You can use `getComputedStyle`

```js
const img = document.getElementById("instaBalas")
function insta() {
  var a = window.getComputedStyle(img);

  if (a.display == "none") {
    img.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    img.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="categoryBtn" onclick="insta()">instagram users</button><br>
<img alt="Imgage" id="instaBalas">
```

Another way I would suggest to have a class and use `classList.toggle()`

```js
const img = document.getElementById("instaBalas")
function insta() {
  img.classList.toggle('hidden')
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button id="categoryBtn" onclick="insta()">instagram users</button><br>
<img alt="Imgage" id="instaBalas">
```

Answer (score 1):

The `style` object on an element doesn't reflect its current styling, it reflects the styles set *directly* on it. So `e.style.display == "none"` is false initially.

If you want to go that route, use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), which returns an object with the "computed"¹ style for the element, taking CSS into account:

```
function insta() {
  var a = document.getElementById("instaBalas");

  if (getComputedStyle(a).display == "none") {
// ---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    a.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    a.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```js
function insta() {
  var a = document.getElementById("instaBalas");

  if (getComputedStyle(a).display == "none") {
    a.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    a.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="categoryBtn" onclick="insta()">instagram users</button>
<div id="instaBalas">instaBalas</div>
```

**BUT**, it would be better to define a class to hide the element, and then use [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) on the element's [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
function insta() {
  document.getElementById("instaBalas").classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function insta() {
    document.getElementById("instaBalas").classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="categoryBtn" onclick="insta()">instagram users</button>
<div id="instaBalas">instaBalas</div>
```

All major browsers have `classList`, and it can be polyfilled for obsolete browsers.

---

¹ It's not really the computed property value, it's the *resolved* or *used* property value, [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10970740/157247).

Comment: really thanks for taking the time it worked. is there any possibility to expand the getComputedStyle(a).display?

Comment: @iammgt - Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that...?

Comment: I mean, can you explain a little more?

Comment: @iammgt - I'm not sure what more to say. :-) I did update the answer after your comment, adding a little bit and linking to MDN's documentation for `getComputedStyle` if that helps...?