# Get element's resolved height CSS property value; recognize 100%

Tags: javascript, css, getcomputedstyle

> The values returned by `getComputedStyle` are **resolved values**. These are usually the same as CSS 2.1’s computed values, but *for some older properties like `width`, **`height`**, or `padding`*, they are instead the same as **used values**.

-- [MDN: window.getComputedStyle() notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Notes)

So is it currently possible to get the **resolved value** of `height` as it was specified in stylesheet?

I.e. know that some element's computed `..px` (= **used**) height was specified as `height: 100%;` in style sheet? (**`100%`** being the **resolved** value in question.)

Is there some new specification regarding this problem in consideration?

---

Edit 2020-08-17: see very similar question and excellent answer from 2012: [Is there a cross-browser method of getting the used css values of all properties of all elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10970655/540955)
(Sadly, noting seem to ave changed since then.)

Comment: To clarify, you're looking to determine the pixel height of an element that has been assigned a percentage value for `height`, correct?

Comment: Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

Comment: No, pixel value (used) is that in the `getComputedStyle(el).height`. What I need is to get literally '`100%`' if the style sheet rule contained `height: 100%;`, or '`12vh`' if it contained `height: 12vh;`.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I believe only way to do *that* would be to manually divide the pixel height by the parentElement, window, or viewport height. I don't think there's a way to get the percentage value back, but I'll check and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no specification or functionality that supports or enables this method. There are plenty of ways to go the other direction, including...

- [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)
- [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)
- [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

... but none that will retrieve the exact percentage specified in the CSS, unfortunately.

You can *try*, as I've done below.

---

## RegEx

If your height is specified as an inline style, you could RegEx it out of the attribute like so<sup>1</sup>:

```js
let elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
let re = /(?<=\height:\s+?)[^\;]+/i;
console.log(re.exec(elem.getAttribute("style"))[0]);
```

```html
<div style="color: black; height: 100%; background: white;"></div>
```

This is terrible practice, though, and could be janky if there are multiple width declarations (which should never happen, but we're already in "bad code land", so why not?). Of course, this ignores the fact that inline styles should generally be avoided in the first place, so this probably won't apply to you.

---

## Bounding calculations

It's also possible to calculate the value yourself by comparing the height of the element with the height of its parent.

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("inner");
let pare = elem.parentElement;

let hrat = `${100*(elem.offsetHeight / pare.offsetHeight)}%`;

console.log(hrat);
```

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,0,0,0.35), rgba(255,0,0,0.35) 10px, rgba(255,0,0,0.1) 10px, rgba(255,0,0,0.1) 20px), linear-gradient(white, white);
}

#inner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: darkgreen;
  mix-blend-mode: hue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

If you add borders, margin, or padding, or the element adapts to the size of its content, though, this calculation will be incorrect.

---

## Conclusion

In conclusion, everything is jank.

In my opinion, you'd be better off not fighting with CSS and JavaScript to coerce the value from the available information, and working out a way to do without the value. I've tried to do this kind of thing many times, so be forewarned: this way lies madness.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>RegEx lookbehinds are [not even remotely close](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) to being fully supported, so shouldn't be used in production.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for ideas hints. I probably shouldn't have used `100` example in the question because it could lead to conclusion I'm looking for way of telling something matches other dimension. What I am actually aiming for is more precisely the '%' / 'vw' / any other units specified part. And also for any source of style, not just inline attribute.

Comment: Presumably it could be extracted from styleSheets using ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025329/ but as I understand it then one would have to write own specificity calculator to get rule that is really in effect. (Presumably that 'madness' you were reffering to :])

Comment: I can say with certainty that it's not possible to determine programmatically for any given unit. You could try to read the `textContent` of `<style>` tags in the document head, and `fetch` the content of any `link[rel='stylesheet']` elements you find, but *please* don't :)

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the `document.styleSheets` property, but it looks like its interfaces are very similar to that of `Node` (namely `nodeType` and its all-caps constants). Madness.

Comment: (note to self) https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421679/540955 seems be answer attempting discussed "sift through stylesheets, calculate specificity and return original rule" approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the stylesheet rule itself. If you know the selector that sets an elements width/height you can do this:

```css
.box {
  width: 12vw;
  background: red;  
}
```

```
<div class="box">red</div>
```

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var rules = sheet.rules;

for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
  if (rules[i].selectorText == '.box') {
    console.log(rules[i].style.width);
  }  
}
```

This will give you the `12vw` you're looking for.

Depending on how your elements are defined, you could in theory create a helper function that gets these values for you by looping through the elements `classList`.